# binary tree always null

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, inner-classes

I know there are a lot of similar questions on here. I've looked at them, but everyone's implementation is different and it's just confusing me. I am trying to make a binary tree. Every time I insert an element, it becomes the root which is not what I want. If I try to access the data at the root from the main method or pass the root into another method, I get a null pointer exception. Can anyone tell me why my root is always null and why my insert method is not assigning a value to the root? Any tips on better design for data structures in Java would also be much appreciated.

```
package interviewQuestions;

public class BinaryTree {
    private Node root = null;

    private class Node {
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        public Node(int dataval){
            data = dataval;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }

    // A binary search tree must have no duplicate nodes
    // Insert nodes into the tree. Return 1 on success.
    public int insert(Node root, int data){
        Node temp = root;
        if(root == null){
            Node node = new Node(data);
            root = node;
            System.out.println("new root is "+root.data);
            return 1;
        }
        else if(temp.data < data && temp.right != null){
            if(data < temp.right.data){
                Node node = new Node(data);
                node.right = temp.right;
                temp.right = node;
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                temp = temp.right;
                insert(temp, data);
            }
        }
        else if(temp.data < data && temp.right == null){
            Node node = new Node(data);
            temp.right = node;
            return 1;
        }
        else if(temp.data > data && temp.left != null){
            if(data > temp.left.data){
                Node node = new Node(data);
                node.left = temp.left;
                temp.left = node;
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                temp = temp.left;
                insert(temp, data);
            }
        }
        else if(temp.data > data && temp.left == null){
            Node node = new Node(data);
            temp.left = node;
            return 1;
        }
            return -1;
    }

    public void preOrder(Node root){
        if(root.left != null){
            System.out.println(root.data);
            root = root.left;
            preOrder(root);
        }
        else if(root.left == null && root.right != null){
            System.out.println(root.data);
            root = root.right;
            preOrder(root);
        }
        else if(root.left == null && root.right == null){
            return;
        }
    }

    // Remove

    // Find

    // Balance


    public static void main (String[] args){
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();

        tree.insert(tree.root, 5);
        tree.insert(tree.root, 2);
        tree.insert(tree.root, 8);
        tree.insert(tree.root, 1);
        tree.insert(tree.root, 3);
        tree.insert(tree.root, 9);
        tree.insert(tree.root, 20);
        tree.insert(tree.root, 10);
        tree.insert(tree.root, 15);

        System.out.println(tree.root);
        tree.preOrder(tree.root);
        System.out.println("Ya. everysing ees güten tag. YA.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should find out by doing some debugging.

Comment: Why are you passing in a root variable when root is a private variable in your class? Fix your insert statement to only receive `data` and change private variable root to equal node. You method causes it to set the parameter `root` to `node`. This results in no change to the classes root.

Comment: Also you never wrote a `toString()` method for the `Node` class so `System.out.println(tree.root)` simply dumps the name of the object(ex. BinaryTree$Node@1db9742)

Comment: OOOO now I get it. I still don't understand the consequences of root being private if I'm only using it within this class though. How does the design improve if I use default visibility instead of private?

Comment: @user137717 You don't change the visibility of the root. When you enter the insert statement you have 2 different root variables in your code; the root you declared in your class and the root you passed as a parameter. You only want the one in the class.

Comment: o, i misunderstood your first comment. you should make these comments into an answer so i can mark this question as closed.

Comment: Whenever you pass a variable to a method, the method will make a copy of that variable (though both variables will still be pointing to the same object). But if you set the variable in the method equal to something else, the first variable will stay unchanged. That's why `tree.root` stays at `null`, even if you set the `root` in the `insert` method equal to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in a root variable when root is a private variable in your class. Fix your insert statement to only receive data and change private variable root to equal node.

Your method causes it to set the parameter root to node. This results in no change to the classes root.

You don't need to change the visibility of the root. When you enter the insert statement you have 2 different root variables in your code; the root you declared in your class and the root you passed as a parameter. You only want the one in the class